# Creating a loading screen in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there any way to create a loading screen in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.insert('1.0' , "hello\n"*5000000)

mainloop()
```

Here, the main window takes some time to pop up, so I would like to create a temporary window that tells the user that some process is going on.

To do this, I did something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

temp_win = Toplevel()
message_label = Label(temp_win , text = "Loading.. Please wait")
message_label.pack()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.insert('1.0' , "hello\n"*5000000)

mainloop()
```

But here, both the windows only pop up only when the `mainloop` function is called, which is of no use.

My goal is to show the temporary window before the main window pops up.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Why is ur app slow?

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich: I made it slow, just for demonstration purposes. As you can see in this line `text.insert('1.0' , "hello\n"*5000000)`, I'm inserting so many lines into the text widget, which makes the app slow.

Comment: Main window takes time to pop up?

Comment: @CoolCloud: Yes, the line `text.insert('1.0' , "hello\n"*5000000)` makes the window take time to pop up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Show splash screen and hide main screen until \_\_init\_\_ has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676617/tkinter-show-splash-screen-and-hide-main-screen-until-init-has-finished)

Comment: To show real delay, use `time.sleep(5)`.

Comment: @CoolCloud: Well, `time.sleep()` adds a delay to the program. But in my real code, the original process itself takes time.

Comment: Let me explain my real situation. I have imported many modules in my original program, so it takes time to import all of them. I would like to show a loading screen at the same time when the modules are getting imported, so that the user can know that some process is going on. Threading does not help, because calling `mainloop` from a different thread causes problems.

Comment: Give the below solution a try, which does use `threading`, but does not communicate with the main tkinter directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the `tkinter` be in main code, but make a function for the splash screen, so its like:

```
import threading
from tkinter import *

started = False
def pop():
    new = Tk()

    l = Label(new,text='Loading')
    l.pack()

    new.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',lambda: new.destroy() if started else False) # Close the window only if main window has shown up
    new.mainloop()

threading.Thread(target=pop).start() # Use this before the heavy process starts

root = Tk()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.insert('1.0' , "hello\n"*5000000) # If you want to see real delay use time.sleep(5)

started = True
root.mainloop()
```

This way there is no relation between the first two instances of `Tk` directly, using a `Toplevel` would require a `Tk` instance to be made first.

Flag `started` is used just to ensure that the splash screen cannot be closed before the main window pops up.

Comment: In this code `new.mainloop()` waits until all windows have been closed. This means that it can fire events even though it is in a different thread. The only solution that shouldn't cause problems is to move all of the non-GUI stuff in the thread and leave everything else in the main thread.

Comment: @TheLizzard That would mean what ever is after `new.mainloop()` would not be executed?

Comment: Correct. `<any tkinter.Tk>.mainloop()` is a blocking call until all `tkinter.Tk` windows are closed. Try it out - add `print("!")` just after `new.mainloop()` and see if it is executed.

Comment: @TheLizzard It did get executed after I closed the splash screen.

Comment: My bad I forgot that that only happens when it is called from an event/`.after` script. So your code should be fine.

Comment: Hey @CoolCloud,  I ran into a small problem. When I try to destroy the loading window once the heavy process has finished, the program stops responding. Do you have any solution for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Lenovo360 The program stopped responding mostly because of the heavy process happening in the same thread

Comment: @CoolCloud: Well, the program does respond when I withdraw the window or don't do anything with it. It only stops responding when I try to destroy it.

Comment: @Lenovo360 Maybe ask a new question about this with detailed explanation

Comment: @CoolCloud: I experimented with this problem, and I think this happens because a  `Tk()` instance created in one thread cannot be controlled with another. I fixed this problem by creating a nested function that get's called recursively and closes the loading window once the value of a variable is set to true.

Comment: @Lenovo360 Yes, two `tkinter` cannot communicate between threads.

Answer (score 1):

`tkinter` doesn't allow you to call it from multiple threads (it might crash without any errors). This means that you can't do any GUI stuff in threads other than the main one/where you create your `Tk()`. Also there are [some bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67007447/11106801) with how `_tkinter` communicates with `tcl`. Keeping that in mind this is what I have:

```py
from time import sleep
import tkinter as tk
from threading import Thread

def non_gui_stuff():
    # We are going to do some work
    sleep(3)


t = Thread(target=non_gui_stuff, daemon=True)
t.start()

root = tk.Tk()
# Hide the main window until the non-GUI stuff is done
root.withdraw()

# Create the loading screen
loading_screen = tk.Toplevel(root)
loading_label = tk.Label(loading_screen, text="Loading")
loading_label.pack()

# While the thread is alive
while t.is_alive():
    # Update the root so it will keep responding
    root.update()
print("Non-GUI thread is done")

loading_screen.destroy()
# Show the main window
root.deiconify()
root.focus_force()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this with threading.

```
import threading
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def loading_screen():
    temp_win = Toplevel()
    message_label = Label(temp_win , text = "Loading.. Please wait")
    message_label.pack()

def main():
    text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
    text.pack()

    text.insert('1.0' , "hello\n"*5000000)

a = threading.Thread(target=loading_screen)
b = threading.Thread(target=main)
a.start()
b.start()
mainloop()
```

Comment: This dosent answers the question. Also have you considered that you creating the instance of `Tk()` in the main thread and construc the children in two different threads, while the children arent shown till the process is finished? This isnt a solution its the same problem in a different way.

Comment: this works fine on my computer. When I run the code the loading screen pops up with text even while the other window is loading

Comment: Also using tkinter from multiple threads might crash tkinter so please don't do it

Comment: ok thank you @TheLizzard for explaining that to me

Comment: @TheLizzard But I think, that if the second `Tk` thread instance does not interfere with the first instance then its fine?

Comment: @CoolCloud Well... It's complicated but I think that it still might crash because the `mainloop()` (btw `root.mainloop()` will have the same effect) waits for all windows to close which means that events will be called from the main thread. And that is a different thread from the one where the `Tk()` was created. Also some times tcl handles things like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67007762/11106801) weirdly.