# When implementing Splash Screen, pyimage doesn't exist anymore

Tags: python, tkinter

So, that's one of the strangest errors I've ever seen in Python. Hopefully, you can help me.

I have a tkinter mainwindow in main_file implementing images via:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageColor

#...

self.image_package_render = Image.open('ImagePackage.png')
self.image_package_render_data = np.array(self.image_package_render.convert('RGBA'))

self.plus_render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image_package_render.resize((14, 14), box=(16, 20, 30, 34)))
```

When I launch the main_file directly, it works like a charm via `root.mainloop()`.

Now I want to implement a splash screen by developing an external script:

```
import tkinter as tk

splash_root = tk.Tk()
splash_root.geometry("200x200")
splash_label = tk.Label(splash_root, text="Splash Screen", font=18)
splash_label.pack()

import main_file

splash_root.destroy()
tk.mainloop()
```

Now, however, main_file doesn't start up and throws me the error "_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage12" doesn't exist".

(Also doesn't work, if I implement the splash_root directly in main_file).

It clearly has something to do with splash_root, but I can't get my head around it.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Solved:

It appears that another mainloop apart from `root.mainloop()` in combination with another window besides a toplevel, just crashes the code somehow.

I implemented a toplevel window as splash like suggested here: [Tkinter Show splash screen and hide main screen until __init__ has finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676617/tkinter-show-splash-screen-and-hide-main-screen-until-init-has-finished)

Thank you!